# How to increment values when add dynamic controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am adding dynamic controls and I want to increment the values in Label when adding controls dynamically

Code:

```
private int controlCount
    {
        get
        {
            int val = 0;
            try
            {
                val = (int)ViewState["ControlCount"];
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // handle exception, if required.
            }
            return val;
        }
        set { ViewState["ControlCount"] = value; }
    }

    protected void addnewtext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = controlCount++;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            AddVisaControl ac = (AddVisaControl)Page.LoadControl("AddVisaControl.ascx");
            Label lb = new Label();
            string z = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
            lb.Text = "Visa " + z;
            rpt1.Controls.Add(lb);
            lb.Attributes.Add("class", "style8");
            rpt1.Controls.Add(ac);
            rpt1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR>"));
        } 
    }
```

In the below image I'm getting label values i.e(Visa 3) are overwriting

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
string z = Convert.ToString(j + 1);
```

rather than

```
string z = Convert.ToString(i + 1);
```

Comment: No worries. To avoid that sort've thing in the future, if your having issues like this, try naming them more meaningful. Its so much easier to notice i is in the wrong place if its called currentTotalCount or something similar.